# How do I reiterate a set of equations in Matlab until convergence?

Tags: matlab, equation-solving

I have three equations, where u is previously defined as an mx1 vector and A is an mxn matrix:

```
v = A'*u/norm(A'*u);
s = norm(A*v);
u = A*v/norm(A*v);
```

I'm trying to reiterate these equations until they converge. I've been trying to use the solve() function:

```
[v s u] = solve(v == A'*u/norm(A'*u), s == norm(A*v), u == A*v/norm(A*v), v, s, u)
```

But I keep getting a whole bunch of errors when using that. How else could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you were expecting using `solve`, but you can do this numerically using a `while` loop until the change in `v` and `u` is smaller than some tolerance.

```
A=rand(5,4); %// sample data
u=rand(5,1);
u2=u+1;v2=1;v=0; %// to make sure we enter the loop
tol=1e-11 %// tolerance on change in u or v, to exit loop
while(norm(u2-u)>tol && norm(v2-v)>tol) %// continue until both changes are small enough
    u2 = u;
    v2 = v;
    v = A'*u/norm(A'*u) %// calculate new value of v
    s = norm(A*v);
    u = A*v/norm(A*v) %// new value of u
end
```

Comment: Stupid me, I didn't even think of using a while loop. I saw a similar question on another forum and they were trying to use the solve() function, so I got it stuck in my head that I should use that. Thanks!